# Can we use cosmosContainer.queryItems() method to execute the delete query on cosmos container

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Java method in my code, in which I am using following line of code to fetch any data from azure cosmos DB

```
  Iterable<FeedResponse<Object>> feedResponseIterator =
      cosmosContainer
          .queryItems(sqlQuery, queryOptions, Object.class)
          .iterableByPage(continuationToken, pageSize);
```

Now the whole method looks like this

```
  public List<LinkedHashMap> getDocumentsFromCollection(
      String containerName, String partitionKey, String sqlQuery) {

    List<LinkedHashMap> documents = new ArrayList<>();
    String continuationToken = null;
    do {
      CosmosQueryRequestOptions queryOptions = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();

      CosmosContainer cosmosContainer = createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, partitionKey);

      Iterable<FeedResponse<Object>> feedResponseIterator =
          cosmosContainer
              .queryItems(sqlQuery, queryOptions, Object.class)
              .iterableByPage(continuationToken, pageSize);

      int pageCount = 0;

      for (FeedResponse<Object> page : feedResponseIterator) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Access all the documents in this result page
        page.getResults().forEach(document -> documents.add((LinkedHashMap) document));

        // Along with page results, get a continuation token
        // which enables the client to "pick up where it left off"
        // in accessing query response pages.
        continuationToken = page.getContinuationToken();
        pageCount++;
        log.info(
            "Cosmos Collection {} deleted {} page with {} number of records in {} ms time",
            containerName,
            pageCount,
            page.getResults().size(),
            (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
      }

    } while (continuationToken != null);
    log.info(containerName + " Collection has been collected successfully");
    return documents;
  }
```

My question is that can we use same line of code to execute delete query like (DELETE * FROM c)? If yes, then what it would be returning us in **Iterable<FeedResponse> feedResponseIterator** object.

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements can only be used for reads. Delete operations must be done using DeleteItem().

Here are Java SDK samples (sync and async) for all document operations in Cosmos DB.

[Java v4 SDK Document Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-java-sdk-samples#document-examples)